# Laravel 4 - Switching config values per environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

Im using Stripe as my payment gateway at the moment,

What i want to do is switch the keys based on the environment

In my start.php i have the following setup

```
'local' => array('mymacpro'),
'production' => array('r2d2.mydomain.com')
```

Is there something i can do like the following in the stripe.php config file.

```
if environment = local then use this key
else use this key
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply follow the instructions here http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration do two files for two environments and put keys there.

like `app/config/stripe.php` and `app/config/local/stripe.php` which contents would be

```
<?php
return [
    'key' => 'KEY',
];
```

then do in your app `Config::get('stripe.key')` and it get switched automatically.